# Place Name from Network operator in Android

Tags: android

How can I obtain the Place Name from the network operator's "Cell Info" in Android (We often get the place-name of the nearest tower in cell info, right ??) I want this place-name as a string to be displayed in a textview control.

Comment: Did you look into the documentation before asking the question?

Comment: which documentations ?? Sorry, I'm new to this field...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at [GSM location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html) documentation and this [tutorial](http://android-coding.blogspot.dk/2011/06/get-cell-location-on-gsm-phone.html) and see if it answers your question. It looks like there is an interface you can use.

Comment: But what I want is that I must get the Place Name as a string (without using GPRS/any other internet connection). My Nokia phone does that somehow, I want the same thing to be done in an app.. Please help me..

Comment: The PDF that comes up when you search for "Android geolocation using GSM network" looks interesting. I am talking about page 14.